# XHR is hitting the server thrice sometimes

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest, intervals, tizen

I am working on Tizen Wearable Web application . 
I am trying to post data to the server using XHR,

```
    function execute()
    var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();

    xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (this.readyState == 4) {
            if (this.status == 200 || this.status == 201) {
                console.log(xhttp.responseText);

                jsonResponse = JSON.parse(xhttp.responseText);

                rheaResponse = jsonResponse.Response;

            }

        } else {
            console.log("Chat FAILED: " + this.status);
        }
    };
    xhttp.open("POST", chatUrl, true);
    xhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
    xhttp.send(sampleData);
 }

 function onBtnTap() {
   recognizer.continuous = false;
    recognizer.onstart = function() {
        isListnining = true;
        console.log("started");
    };

    recognizer.onend = function() {
        isListnining = false
        console.log("Recogniztion API stopped");
    }
    recognizer.start();
    timer = setTimeout(stopRecognition, 8000);
    recognizer.onresult = function(event) {
        console.log("On result");
        isListnining = false;

        clearTimeout(timer);
            if (event.results.length > 0) {

            userInput = event.results[0][0].transcript;

            updateArrays(position, userInput);

            console.log(userInput);

            execute(userInput);
        }
    }

    recognizer.onerror = function(event) {
        isListnining = false
        console.log('Speech recognition error detected: ' + event.error);
    }
```

}

Everything is working fine but sometimes i am getting the response twice , thrice and more. Assuming somewhere request is hitting the server multiple times. Please let me know whats wrong in the code? why is it hitting the server multiple times.

Comment: How/when/where is the `XMLHttpRequest` called? Do you have any time intervals set to loop the calls or anything like that in place? If this is run by `setInterval` you might find that the interval has run again before receiving a response from the first request which will then Que the response and execute when complete.

Comment: @NewToJS Hi,  Yes i have time interval. i have updated the code. i have a speechrecognition and i set setInterval() for 8seconds if speechrecognition doesnt recognize anything then it will stop the recognition.

Comment: What is your speechrecognition response time?  It would be better if you call the method which consist XMLHttpRequest after completing the task of speechrecognition.